# Php Updating table

Tags: php

```
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE tblregistration SET firstname='$firstname' ,lastname='$lastname',Home_Address='$Haddress',Church_Name='$Churchname',Church_Address='$CAddress',Zone='$zones',District='$dis',Dob='$Dobs',Age='$age',Gsm='$Telephone',
Sex='$sexs',Email='$Emails',Health_Challenges='$HealthIssue',Pastor='$PastorNm',Pastor_Mobile='$PastorMb',Councellor_Name='$Councellornm',Councellor_Mobile='$Councellornum',Next_of_kin_name='$noks',Next_of_kin_mobile='$nokmobiles',Parent_name='$lastname ',
Candidate_sig='$firstname',Head_councellor_sig='$Councellornm',category='$category',Amount='$amt',TellerNumber='$TellNumber',dat='$dates',PayDate='$Paydate',BankName='$Bank',yearr='$yearr' WHERE reg_id='$f'");

$res = mysql_query($up) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$up);
```

I keep getting thhis Error Message.

> Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1 in 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\conference\update.php on line 688

Comment: What does the query look like after the variables are interpolated?

Comment: Probably some string you are trying to insert contain quotes and they are not properly escaped

Comment: just be glad your update didn't involve [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)!

Comment: You can start by removing the space `Parent_name='$lastname ',` however I doubt that'll do it. I'm under the impression you're trying to enter `Bob's sister said: "Hey Bob, what's the forecast for today?"` Bob said "Tonight's forecast will be dark." - Use `stripslashes()` along with `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 4):

You're double-executing your query:

```
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE ...");
       ^^^^^^^^^^^--- execute your query and return a statement handle
$res= mysql_query($up);
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---take your statement handle and try to execute it
```

Try

```
$sql = "UPDATE ...";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

instead

The specific cause of your error: Your second `mysql_query()` call is using the result handle of your FIRST mysql_query() call as the SQL string. the query call expects a string and so it takes that statement handle and treats it like a string. But a "stringified" statement handle DOESN'T give you the original sql string. The handle's just an internal pointer to a structure inside the mysql_*() code complex somewhere, which is where the `1` comes from. To PHP, it literally looks like you're doing

```
$result = mysql_query('1');
```

Comment: This is good advice, but you'll probably still get the same error message. Once you've switched to this way of running the query, use echo $sql; to see how your variables are being added to the query. It's either a wrongly escaped string, or an empty non-string value that is causing this problem.

Comment: @vic3685: wrong. if the first query had failed, then it'd be a boolean FALSE, aka '0'. not '1'. The query is still vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, but in this specific case, it actually did work properly.

Comment: That makes sense. [`Here I thought`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268387/php-updating-table#comment39372988_25268387) the weather was going to be different. 'twas the case for another question yesterday; but not here obviously. Very well explained.